# Extra double quotes are getting added when using jmeter variable to pass value in GraphQL HTTP request 'Variable' in Jmeter

Tags: graphql, jmeter

I want to send below request in GraphQL HTTP request in Jmeter -

```
{"pageName":"TEST_SCREEN","section":"TEST_SCREEN","action":{"name":"includeObjects","fields":[{"fieldName":"id_","value":"101"},{"fieldName":"id_","value":"102"},{"fieldName":"id_","value":"103"}]}}
```

I am generating the value of "fields" dynamically and it can have any number of entries. So I generated value for fields and stored in a variable beforehand like below-

```
String request = "[";
for (int i = 0 ;i<items.length;i++) {
    if (!"[".equals(request)) {
        request +=",";
    }   
    request += "{\"fieldName\":\"id_\",\"value\":\""+items[i]+"\"}";
}
request += "]";
vars.put("ITEMS_ID_REQUEST",request);
```

Then in the graphQL Sample, under Variables I gave like this-

```
{"pageName":"NEW_PAGE","section":"NEW_FILTER_PAGE","action":{"name":"includeAction","fields":"${ITEMS_ID_REQUEST}"}}
```

JMeter is sending below reuest-

```
{"pageName":"TEST_SCREEN","section":"TEST_SCREEN","action":{"name":"includeObjects","fields":"[{"fieldName":"id_","value":"54794"},{"fieldName":"id_","value":"54795"},{"fieldName":"id_","value":"54796"},{"fieldName":"id_","value":"54797"},{"fieldName":"id_","value":"54798"}]"}}
```

And my sample is failing. I notice that value of the fields which should be [{..}] is now enclosed in a double quotes which is messing up the json request. I know we have to enclose JMeter variable in double quotes so removing them didn't work so I tried to escape double quotes but that also isn't working.
How can I replace the desired value correctly without double quotes?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think this is **you** who adds the "double quotes", not JMeter

```
"fields":"${ITEMS_ID_REQUEST}"}}                                         
         ^ here              ^ and here
```

so just remove them and they will go away in your "below request"

Maybe using [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) will be more convenient for generating JSON than string concatenation?

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: I tried adding the variable without the double quotes like this "fields":${ITEMS_ID_REQUEST} But I am getting following error on saving the changes- Ignoring the GraphQL query variables content due to the syntax error: Unrecognized token '$'

Comment: I was using JMeter 5.4 and there was an issue that we cannot use variables in GraphQL Variables without double quotes(https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65108), which is now fixed. After taking latest JMeter I am able to use variables without double quotes in GraphQL Variables.